# Javascript ajax get request returning json file readystate 1 rather than data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to call this web service to return the city/state address of a given zipcode. I am sure I simply just don't understand ajax correctly.

```js
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://ziptasticapi.com/28403",
    dataType: "json",
    
});

    var address = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(address);
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive data in `success` callback.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://ziptasticapi.com/28403",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(address) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(address))
    }   
});
```

Also, there is a syntax error in your call, you can't have comma after last key value pair in Javascript object.

Comment: Thank you. In that fassion is something of this nature possible?

Comment: var data = $.ajax({
    
type: "GET",
    url: "https://ziptasticapi.com/28403",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(address){
       var parced = JSON.stringify(address);
}
});

    
    alert(parced);

Comment: The variable `parced` needs to be declared before it can be used. `success` is among one of the branches which can be taken when `$.ajax` is called. It would thus be best to declare it before ajax call is made, or you need to check if `typeof parced !== 'undefined'` before displaying it.

Comment: i declaired parced var parced; before the ajax call but it doesnt exicute to my alert after the ajax call.

Comment: That was a simple syntax error sorry but it is saying parced is undefined. Does this mean there is something wrong with my webservices call?

Answer (score 0):

To do a simple API call, do the following:

```
$.getJSON('**WEB_URL_API_ENDPOINT**', function(data){


     console.log(data);

});
```

Check the console to see how the data is coming back as (single, list, etc..)

Then depending on how the data will be coming back (single, list, etc..), you can do some of these different methods.

Simple loop to push elements to a list:

```
$.getJSON('**WEB_URL_API_ENDPOINT**', function(data){

  var dataList = []
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    dataList.push([data[i].city, data[i].state, data[i].address, 
    data[i].zipcode]);
  }

});
```

If the data is not coming back in a list form, you should be able to just grab the elements based on their name.

```
$.getJSON('**WEB_URL_API_ENDPOINT**', function(data){

 var city = data.city;
 var state = data.state;
 var address = data.address;
 var zipcode = data.zipcode;

});
```